# Replace If else in C Sharp

Tags: c#, if-statement, optimization, design-patterns, delegates

This is my Business Layer Code
public void UpdateRecords()
{

```
int resultCountries = 0
int resultState = 0
int resultDistrict = 0
int resultCity = 0
DataTable dt = dataAccess.GetRecords();
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{    
    int PersonId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PersonId"].ToString());
    resultCountries = dataAccess.UpdateCountries(PersonId);
    if(resultCountries > 0)
    {
        dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"Country Updated Successfully");
        resultState = UpdateState(personId);
        if(resultState > 0)
        {
            dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"State Updated Successfully");    
            resultDistrict = UpdateDistrict(personId);
            if(resultDistrict > 0)
            {
                dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"District Updated Successfully");
                resultCity = UpdateCity(personId);
                if(resutlCity > 0)
                {
                    dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"City Updated Successfully");
                    continue;
                }
                else if(resutlCity == 0)
                {
                    dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"City Not Updated Successfully");
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"Some error occured while updating city...");
                    continue;            
                }        
        
            }
            else if(resultDistrict  == 0)
            {
                dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"District not Updated Successfully");
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"Some error occured while updating district..");
                continue;
            }        
        }
        else if(resultState  == 0)
        {
                dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"State not Updated Successfully");
                continue;
        }
        else
        {
            dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"Some error occured while updating state..");
            continue;
        }        
    }
    else if(resultCountries == 0)
    {
        dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"Country not Updated Successfully");
        continue;
    }
    else 
    {
        dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId,"Some error occured");
        continue;
    }
}
```

}

From business Layer  I am calling data access layer methods,UpdateCountries,UpdateState,UpdateDistrict,UpdateCity which are updating country, state,district,city against personId in person table.

If country update is successful,state is updated otherwise log the error in db and update next record. Same is done for state,district,city. But here there are lots of if else used,kindly let me know how to replace if else in code. Do not want to use switch case or ternary operator,also not allowed to use stored procedure. The dataaccess layer methods return integer value of 1 if update is successfull,0 if condition is not satisfied,-1 if error.

Comment: Why not just update all those fields at once?

Comment: Only state,country,city or district are not getting updated. There are lot of columns in different tables getting updated. This is just an example I posted for how to replace if else.

Comment: Updated with what? All you are passing is an Id.

Answer (score 1):

**For academic intrigue and curiosity only**

You could use a list of delegate

```
var list = new List<(string Name, Func<int, int> Callback)>()
{
   ("Country", dataAccess.UpdateCountries),
   ("State", dataAccess.UpdateState),
   ("District", dataAccess.UpdateDistrict),
   ("City", dataAccess.UpdateCity),
};


DataTable dt = dataAccess.GetRecords();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   var personId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PersonId"].ToString());
   foreach (var (name, callback) in list)
   {
      switch (callback(personId))
      {
         case > 0:
            dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId, $"{name} Updated Successfully");
            continue;
         case 0:
            dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId, $"{name} not Updated Successfully");
            break;
         default:
            dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId, "Some error occurred");
            break;
      }

      break;
   }
}
```

**However**

You should be doing this all in the one request and one round trip to the database, as such this problem should likely be rethought and refactored.

Comment: I am getting error while adding methods in list can not convert string,nethod group to string name,func<int,int> callback

Comment: @aniketnarvankar I cant see what you have done, however the logic is right, its likely you have made a mistake, or you will need to adapt it to your code

Answer (score 0):

As it appears that you're using the result of your update process to determine whether to process the next dependency and change the wording of an indication message then perhaps you could use a `Dictionary`
For example something along the lines of:

```
   var messageDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>()
   {
       { 1, "Updated Successfully" },
       { 0, "Not updated successfully"},
       {-1, "Some error occurred while updating "}
   };
```

Then as a first pass you `if..else...` logic would become:

```
int PersonId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PersonId"].ToString());
var result = dataAccess.UpdateCountries(PersonId);
dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId, $"Country {messageDictionary[result]}");

if (result > 0)
{
    result = UpdateState(personId);
    dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId, $"State {messageDictionary[result]}");
    if (result >0)
    {
        result = UpdateDistrict(personId);
        dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId, $"District {messageDictionary[result]}");
        if (result > 0)
        {
            result = UpdateCity(personId);
            dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId, $"City {messageDictionary[result]}");
        }
    }
}
```

If you implemented the suggestion by @TheGeneral then you would have:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   var personId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PersonId"].ToString());
   foreach (var (name, callback) in list)
   {
      var result = callback(personId);
      dataAccess.UpdateMessage(personId, $"{name} {messageDictionary[result]}");
      if(result!=1) break;
   }
}
```